# Application.OnKey for one workbook of multiple open workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I use Application.OnKey to disable some keys. If I have additional workbooks open it is applied to these as well. Where should I put the code so that it only works for the intended workbook?

This is the code, which I have in "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.Name = "Professional" Then
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", ""
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", ""
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", ""
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", ""
Else
    Application.OnKey "{UP}"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}"
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}"
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's changing application properties so can't restrict to one workbook - as you discovered. Maybe use Worksheet_Deactivate or Workbook_SheetSelectionChange or Workbook_WindowDeactivate event to change settings back.

Comment: *if I have additional workbooks opened..* You could close those workbooks if they are not needed in that moment, and reopen them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use `Workbook_Activate` and `Workbook_Deactivate`, in the next way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
 If Sh.Name = "Professional" Then
   Application.OnKey "{UP}", ""
   Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", ""
   Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", ""
   Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", ""
 Else
   Application.OnKey "{UP}"
   Application.OnKey "{DOWN}"
   Application.OnKey "{LEFT}"
   Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}"
 End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
   Application.OnKey "{UP}"
   Application.OnKey "{DOWN}"
   Application.OnKey "{LEFT}"
   Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, But i found an error while running this code **Object variable or With block variable not set**

Comment: @vishnu reji: Upps... I missed the sheet object. Please, use the updated code answer. It uses your initial event, but brings the keys to their standard    status when the workbook is deactivated (`Workbook_Deactivate()` event)...