# Error when disabling keys on a workbook using Application.OnKey and Workbook_Activate()

Tags: excel

I have a specific document I am trying to prevent people from cutting, copying, or pasting to and from. I found a few different snippets of VBA online have managed to get it to work, however, when I click the button to apply the script, any other open document/workbook also becomes locked.

This VBA script is only located in the specific document I need and nowhere else, under 'ThisWorkbook' portion specifically.

```
Private Sub DisableXCV()
With Application
.OnKey "^x", ""
.OnKey "^c", ""
.OnKey "^v", ""
.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = False
.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = False
.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = False
End With
End Sub
```

I tried to add an if condition to check if the workbook name is 'xyz' before applying, but that did not work.

```
Private Sub DisableXCV()
If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "insert workbookname here" Then
With Application
.OnKey "^x", ""
.OnKey "^c", ""
.OnKey "^v", ""
.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = False
.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = False
.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = False
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help or guidance I can get here.

EDIT:
I have tried implementing the solution found and posted here by Scott Craner this past friday.
([Application.OnKey for one workbook of multiple open workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371338/application-onkey-for-one-workbook-of-multiple-open-workbooks))

I am, however, getting an error doing so:
"Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Within the VBA editor, the left drop down menu is selected as 'Workbook' and the right drop down menu is selected as 'Activate' and 'Deactivate' respectively.

The code being

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate(ByVal sh As Object)
If sh.Name = "System Checks" Then
    Application.OnKey "^{x}", ""
    Application.OnKey "^{c}", ""
    Application.OnKey "^{v}", ""
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = False
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = False
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = False
Else
    Application.OnKey "^{x}"
    Application.OnKey "^{c}"
    Application.OnKey "^{v}"
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^{x}"
    Application.OnKey "^{c}"
    Application.OnKey "^{v}"
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put it in workbook_worksheetActivate and reverse it on deactivate back to nothing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371338/application-onkey-for-one-workbook-of-multiple-open-workbooks

Comment: In the link you provided, the person who answered writes to "Please, use Workbook_Activate and Workbook_Deactivate". 

I am fairly new to VBA. Does this mean that while the document is open, it will apply these rules and then re-enable while it is closed? Or does it mean while that specific workbook is not the active window?

I am also unsure how to apply this to a macro button in this case as having tried to do as written there, for my case, the macro is no longer visible in the window to choose a macro to apply to the button.

Comment: workbook_activate fires when the workbook gains focus and deactivate when it loses activation.  You would not use a button.  The event will fire the code as needed without the need for manual intervention.

Comment: I currently have the following, under 'ThisWorkbook', however I am still able to cut, copy, and paste within the document.


Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)

If sh.Name = "2023 Effluent_MacroEnabled_Example" Then
    Application.OnKey "^x", ""
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.OnKey "^v", ""
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = False
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = False
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = False
Else

Comment: Application.OnKey "^x"
    Application.OnKey "^c"
    Application.OnKey "^v"
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1).Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(2).Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(3).Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Comment: Apologies for comment spam, unsure how to do codeblock here and limited on characters.

Comment: I copy pasted the VBA scripts to a fresh document and it all works now. Not sure what the problem was that would have caused it to just not work on the original document but it is working for me now. 

Thank you again for the help Scott!